# How to plot negative numbers in Y-axis in Excel 2013

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have created a chart of Sales and Growth over a period of years... The growth is negative in a couple of years.

A normal combo chart with Sales in Primary Axis and Growth in Secondary axis looks like this:

[image: This is the combo chart]

The negative values should go down below the x-axis, below the year labels.

I achieved it by merging two different charts, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do it in a single chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel can do this with one relatively minor tweak. You need to change the min/max values in your primary axis to include a negative range to allow your secondary axis to fall negative as well.  Using your data, I assigned the values:

- Primary Axis:   Min -10 Max 90
- Secondary Axis: Min -.1 Max .9

This keeps the general proportions between the axis and allows a negative space for each.  If your values change dramatically, it may be difficult to find a good combination of values.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: Negative Secondary Axis]

But, just because Excel can do this, doesn't mean that you should.  [Stephen Few has a few thoughts about this](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf), and [Jon Peltier has an alternative](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-column-chart-primary-secondary-axes/).  One of the core problems with this type of chart combination is that your measuring two very different things (actual values and proportions) and those don't have the same scale or order of magnitude.  You may be better served by two completely separate charts, rather than combining two dissimilar things on the same chart.

Comment: Well that works fine... Thanks for the related info on charts as well...