# How do I plot multiple data sets with different x and y values on one graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have been trying to plot two data sets in excel 2013 on an XY straight line graph. Both sets are plots of absorption (Y) against time (X), but absorption was measured at different times for each data set.

I'd like to plot both data sets of absorption (Y) on one time axis (X) but I can't find a way to include the two different sets of X variables, as if I plot the different Y series it will plot both against the X values of the first series.

Can anyone advise as to if it is possible to plot my data in this way? (I also have access to excel 2010 if it was something that was possible there.)

Edit: These are excerpts from my data sets:

Set 1

```
Time/s          0 -   10 -   23 -   24 -   32 -   45 -   59 -   66
Absorption   1.13 - 1.90 - 1.95 - 2.01 - 2.02 - 2.06 - 2.09 - 2.16
```

Set 2:

```
Time/s        40  -  120 -   150 -  240 -  320 -  390 
Absorption   1.38 - 1.31 -  1.43 - 1.45 - 1.53 - 1.55
```

I'm aware the x axis values are very different here but I'm hoping to plot another graph with three data sets on (two of which I am yet to collect) and these should have more similar ranges on the x axis. I was just trying the graphing out for now.

Comment: Check this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/715276/how-to-plot-negative-numbers-in-y-axis-in-excel-2013)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. If you can give us an example of your data set, it may help us better understand.

Comment: If you need to create scientific plot, maybe you may think to python and matplotlib or more easily to gnuplot...

Comment: Thank you! I have added in some data but I'll look into those others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your plot to have data from both sets you can achieve it by

- Select the plot
- Goto "Design" tab and "Select Data"
- "Add" the new series and select data points in new series

And it will look like

[image]

But if you are worried about the spread of data in set 1 and set 2, and difficulty in pattern understanding, you can switch x & y and you can use secondary axis. This plot will look like

[image]

Hope you wanted either of this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd not realised that setting the x axis was individual to each set of data and had assumed it couldn't be changed. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure you use an XY Scatter chart, otherwise the X values of the two series are linked.