# Line plot with two lines which have different x and y series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have been doing an experiment were I studied a process in which the decrease of the number of computers in a network over time led to a decrease in that networks performance (at a task). I have measured this under two different conditions. Now I have two tables in Excel 2016 as follows (example):

`Computers | performance
 25        | 10
 14        | 7
 11        | 5
 4         | 0
 1         | 0
 0         | 0`

And second table (in a different sheet):

`Computers | performance
 25        | 12
 16        | 9
 13        | 7
 9         | 6
 4         | 3
 3         | 2
 2         | 0
 0         | 0`

The number of computers is always between 25 and 0, the performance is always between 0 and 12. How can I create a line or scatter plot that shows both tables in one chart? I imagine having one line for each table in separate colors. The number of computers should be on the x-axis, so the x-axis should go from 0 to 25, preferably in descending order. The performance should be on the y-axis, so that should go from 0 to 12.

I am using Excel 2016. I have seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1079157/how-do-i-plot-two-different-data-sets-that-have-different-x-axis) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1053070/how-do-i-plot-multiple-data-sets-with-different-x-and-y-values-on-one-graph), but neither answer my question because I do not really understand the comment on the first one and the second one just says "add the series", but not how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start out by just making a scatter plot of one of your datasets, then you can right click the graph and choose "select data". From there you can add another series with your second data set.

Afterwards you can play with the axis options to get your X axis to be reversed. As long as I'm understanding what you're trying to do, it should look [something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8mjG.jpg)

Comment: Ahh, I see that I mis-entered one of your performance values, but you get the idea.